# How to read csv file with python 3

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.7

I want to read a csv file with python3.7, but my code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_to_csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in csv_data:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 24: invalid start byte
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
csv_data =  csv.reader(open('videos.export-full.csv', 'r'), delimiter=';') 
for row in csv_data:
    print (row)
```

How can I solve this issue and insert the records in the database?
You can download a copy of the csv file from http://li2146-47.members.linode.com/videos.export-full.csv to test it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: CSV files and Unicode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725308/python-3-csv-files-and-unicode-error)

Comment: no it does not answer my question

Comment: `open`  will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding, you should specify the encoding by `open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
import csv

csv_data =  csv.reader('videos.export-full.csv')

for row in csv_data:

print (row)
```

It should work

Comment: it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_to_csv.py", line 14, in <module>
    for row in csv_data:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 24: invalid start byte`

Comment: retry what exactly, i do not understand

Comment: @Jsdoee: I have edited the code and outputs a list.

Answer (score 0):

`'\xb3'` is the unicode code for `³` (SUPERSCRIPT THREE). The error is a hint that the file is not UTF-8 encoded but is probably ISO-8859-1 (or Latin1) encoded. So you should use:

```
csv_data =  csv.reader(open('videos.export-full.csv', 'r', encoding='Latin1'), delimiter=';')
```

You should control the data because `Latin1` is able to convert any byte whatever the encoding, but if encoding is not ISO-8859-1, you do not get the expected characters.

Comment: it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_to_csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    for row in csv_data:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`

Comment: @Jsdoee did you try the ISO encoding as well?

Comment: LookupError: unknown encoding: ISO

Comment: @Jsdoee: If you got a null byte, data could be in UTF16. You should try utf_16_le or utf_16_be.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong and misleading. There is not binary representation of unicode (and also not useful for the rest of the answer).